# Lower and Sup Sums [Integration, partitions]

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, partitions-for-integration

So i have this problem.
Let 
$f(x)$= {$x^2$ if -3$\le$ $x$ $\le$ 1, $-2x$ if $1$$\lt$$x$$\le$$2$
And $P$={$x_0$,...,$x_n$} a partition of [-3,2]. If $1$$\in$[$x_i-1$,$x_i$], find $m_i$, $M_i$, i.e, $m_i$=inf and $M_i$=$sup${$f(x)$:$x$$\in$[$x_{i-1}$,$x_i$]} and for the given partition write the expretion for the sup and low sums. 
And b) Let $g$ be a continous function in $[a,b]$, if 
$L(g,P)$$\le$$2018A$$\le$$U(g,P)$, for any partition of $[a,b]$, show that 
$A=$$\frac{1}{2018}$$\int_a^b$$g(t)dt$.

So this is my attempt for (a) (i know im wrong but i dont know what to do im a little confused in both problems hope that you guys help me)

So we know that 1$\in$[$x_{i-1}$,$x_i$] and for $x^2$ and $-2x$ then

$m_i$=$inf${-2}$=-2$

$M_i$=$sup${1}$=1$

Hence for low and sup sums respectively and because [-3,2] we have

$L(f,P)$=$\sum_{i=1}^n$$-2$$(b-a)$=$-10$

And similarly for the sup sum

we have that is equal to 5.

But i know that in this problem we have four cases right? and in 1 we have troubles but i dont see it can you guys help me to solve this?

In part (b) i have this

Because g es continous in $[a,b]$ then g is integrable.
Given $\epsilon$$\gt$0 we have

0$\le$$L(g,P)$-$U(g,P)$$\le$$\epsilon$

then by hypotesis 
$L(g,P)$$\le$$2018A$$\le$$U(g,P)$ for all partition in [a,b], then

0$\le$$L(g,P)$-$U(g,P)$$\le$$2018A$$\le$$\epsilon$

And for $L(g,P)$-$U(g,P)$

given an arbitrary partition such that for this partition occurs:

0$\le$$|g-A|$$\le$$\epsilon$

0$\le$$|g-2018A|$$\le$$\epsilon$

$|g-2018A|$=0

$A$=$\frac{1}{2018}$$\int_a^b$$g(t)dt$

In this problem i dont know how to argue or i dont know if this is right for an arbitrary partition. Help please

$|g-A|$$\le$$\epsilon$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) I think the definition of $M_i$ should be $M_i=\sup \left\{ f(x):x \in [x_{i-1},x_i] \right\}$, if so i suggest you to edit your post.

To answer this question is really helpfull to draw the graph of $f$[image]

Now you only know that $1 \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$ but you don't know how long is $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ .

So you have to study different cases, for example:

if $x_{i-1} \leq -1$ then $M_i=f(x_{i-1})$

if $x_{i-1} \geq -1$ then $M_i=f(1)=1$, (remember that there is a condition on $[x_{i-1},x_i]$, namely $1 \in [x_{i-1},x_i]$

Can you continue with the study of the different cases?

The same strategy can be adopted to find $m_i$ in the different cases.

(b)$g$ is continuous so if we write $\delta=\max \left\{ |x_{i+1}-x_i|:x_i \in P \right\}$ then $\lim_{\delta \to 0}L(g,P)=\int_a^b g dx= \lim_{\delta \to 0}U(g,P)$ so if we do the limit of the inequality $L(g,P) \leq 2018A \leq U(g,P)$ we can conclude that  $\int_a^b g dx \leq 2018 A \leq \int_a^b g dx$, from wich we can conclude the thesis.

In the proof I stealthy used some important stuff on the limits, for examples that the above limit preserve the inequalities in this sense:
$L(g,P) \leq 2018A \implies \lim_{\delta \to 0}L(g,P) \leq 2018A $.

Comment: I draw a graphic but i still confused a little bit if only can u see what i draw. 
This topic is a little confused to me i still no see it the cases i mean, i can see it from the graphic but i dont know im confused can i send u what i do in my notes?
I see that the $inf$ = $0$ right?

And for the part (b) u can proceed directly? i mean i dont use epsilon first?, i.e,

$0$ $\le$ $L(g,P)$ - $U(g,P)$ $\le$ $\epsilon$ ?

Comment: (a)remember that $f$ has negative values in $(1,2]$, and that $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ may have intersection not empty with $(1,2]$, so $\inf f$ had to be negative.The point to study different cases is because $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$ is not fixed.I suggest you to write down the definition of infimum of a function over a set

Comment: (b)I'm not sure to have understood completely your comment; yes, you could prove the statement using just the definitions and don't use any property of the limits, it can also be usefull and educational doing that way. I would point out that by definition you have $U(g,P) \geq L(g,P) $, can you correct your proof with this? Can you continue the proof?

Comment: Oh ok in that sense i understand the proof for i actually do it and for (b)
 i sincerly i cant do it the part (a) little confused to me u.u

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is what i draw]

I draw this and i dont know, i see that there must be four summatory right?, and if we zoom that part of the graphic we see that 0 is the inf right? im a little confused in this problem